# Responsive Nav Bug

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am trying out the responsive nav plugin (responsive-nav.com) with the basic Skeleton grid system, and for some reason without editing the js and general css for the responsive nav plugin, I am running into issues with the navigation when minimized to area where navicon appears. For some reason the links drop down automatically and the navicon does not appear. Does it have to do with the container? I tried without the container div and still ran into the issue See images for example:

[image: Full Sized Nav]

[image: Navicon Size]

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Your Page Title Here :)</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/layout.css">
    <script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicons
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

</head>
<body>



    <!-- Primary Page Layout
    ================================================== -->


<div class="band-nav">    

    <div class="container">

        <div class="sixteen columns">
         <nav class="nav-collapse">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

 </div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="band-content">

<div class="container">

        <div class="sixteen columns">
            <h1 class="remove-bottom" style="margin-top: 40px">Skeleton</h1>
            <h5>Version 1.2</h5>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="one-third column">
            <h3>About Skeleton?</h3>
            <p>Skeleton is a small collection of well-organized CSS files that can help you rapidly develop sites that look beautiful at any size, be it a 17" laptop screen or an iPhone. It's based on a responsive grid, but also provides very basic CSS for typography, buttons, forms and media queries. Go ahead, resize this super basic page to see the grid in action.</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

   <script>
      var navigation = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse", {
        animate: true,        // Boolean: Use CSS3 transitions, true or false
        transition: 250,      // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
        label: "Menu",        // String: Label for the navigation toggle
        insert: "after",      // String: Insert the toggle before or after the navigation
        customToggle: "",     // Selector: Specify the ID of a custom toggle
        openPos: "relative",  // String: Position of the opened nav, relative or static
        jsClass: "js",        // String: 'JS enabled' class which is added to <html> el
        init: function(){},   // Function: Init callback
        open: function(){},   // Function: Open callback
        close: function(){}   // Function: Close callback
      });
    </script>
<!-- End Document
================================================== -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*
* Skeleton V1.2
* Copyright 2011, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 6/20/2012
*/

/* Table of Content
==================================================
    #Site Styles
    #Page Styles
    #Media Queries
    #Font-Face */

/* #Site Styles
================================================== */


/*! responsive-nav.js 1.0.25 by @viljamis */



.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.nav-collapse li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse li {
    width: 25%;
    *width: 24.9%; /* IE7 Hack */
    _width: 19%; /* IE6 Hack */
  }
}

.nav-collapse a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
  }
}

.nav-collapse ul ul a {
  background: #ececec;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse ul ul a {
    display: none;
  }
}

.nav-toggle {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 70px;
  height: 55px;
  float: right;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f4421a url("hamburger.gif") no-repeat 50% 33%;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 / 1), screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
  .nav-toggle {
    background-image: url("hamburger-retina.gif");
    -webkit-background-size: 100px 100px;
    -moz-background-size: 100px 100px;
    -o-background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
  }
}




/* #Page Styles
================================================== */

/* #Media Queries
================================================== */

    /* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {}

    /* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {}

    /* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

    /* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {}

    /* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {}


/* #Font-Face
================================================== */
/*  This is the proper syntax for an @font-face file
        Just create a "fonts" folder at the root,
        copy your FontName into code below and remove
        comment brackets */

/*  @font-face {
        font-family: 'FontName';
        src: url('../fonts/FontName.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/FontName.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
             url('../fonts/FontName.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/FontName.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../fonts/FontName.svg#webfontZam02nTh') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal; }
*/
```

Comment: ["Uncaught ReferenceError: responsiveNav is not defined "](http://jsbin.com/iZoXoVAL/1/edit). You're not loading Skeleton or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you forgot to link to the jquery library. You are only linking to the jquery of the responsive nav, but you need the Main jquery library to work.

put this before the link to the responsive-nav.js:

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the responsive nav error with this refference:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/responsive-nav.js/1.0.32/responsive-nav.min.js'></script>
```

So I had to download it and host it on my local resources:

```
<script src="/js/responsive-nav.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Problem solved for me.